# dropdown select and down arrow automove refering to text length

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a transparent dropdown select with down arrow. The problem is that the arrow is always the same position from the text no matter if the text is short or long like this:

[image]

As you can see above there is a big gap between text and the arrow but it has to be for a longer text to fit. (it doesn't look good)

I'd like to have this done in two ways (it depends on which side of the website I'll have the select box):

**1) Auto move the arrow to left like always 7px from the text (no matter if the text is short or long).**

[image]

**2) Auto move the text to right like 7px always from the arrow (no matter if the text is short or long).**

[image]

So, this is my code (better view under this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqcfg9L4/1/)):

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="dropDownArrow"></div>
    <select class="selectClass">
        <option>short</option>
        <option>very long text</option>
        <option>long test</option>
    </select>
```

**CSS:**

```
.dropDownArrow {position: absolute; left: 140px; top: 20px; width: 0;    height: 0; border-left: 5px solid transparent; border-right: 5px solid transparent; border-top: 5px solid #7c7c7c;}
.selectClass {-webkit-appearance: none; -webkit-border-radius: 0; -moz-appearance: none; border: none; background: transparent; height: 30px; width: 140px; font-size: 18px; padding-left: 80px; position: absolute; color: #7c7c7c; outline: none;}
select option {background: #EFEFEF; color:#7c7c7c;}
select:-moz-focusring {color: transparent; text-shadow: 0 0 0 #7c7c7c;}
```

**How to fix the code? the best would be to use only CSS but I'm not sure if it's possible without JS (or jQuery).**

```css
.dropDownArrow {position: absolute; left: 140px; top: 20px; width: 0; height: 0; border-left: 5px solid transparent; border-right: 5px solid transparent; border-top: 5px solid #7c7c7c;}
.selectClass {-webkit-appearance: none; -webkit-border-radius: 0; -moz-appearance: none; border: none; background: transparent; height: 30px; width: 140px; font-size: 18px; padding-left: 0px; position: absolute; color: #7c7c7c; outline: none;}
select option {background: #EFEFEF; color:#7c7c7c;}
select:-moz-focusring {color: transparent; text-shadow: 0 0 0 #7c7c7c;}
```

```html
  <div class="dropDownArrow"></div>
  <select class="selectClass">
   <option>short</option>
   <option>very long text</option>
   <option>long test</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

*(I would comment, but I'm too low on points)*

You should ask yourself if this dynamic width is really needed. It's not what users are used to, and might lower the user experience.

I don't believe it is posible with CSS. For most cases you can CSS pseudo elements, like `:before`, but that doesn't work for `<select>`.

Here's a ["quick 'n dirty fiddle"](https://jsfiddle.net/46mvya90/) giving you an example with JS:

```
$(function() {
  $(".selectClass").on("change", function() {
     var $this = $(this);
     var $arrow = $("#dropDownArrow1");
     var dynamicWidth = $this.val().length * 10; // May work for most cases or not
     var dropdownArrowStaticArmLength = -8;
     if (dynamicWidth <= 50) // one of the "not"s
       dynamicWidth = 65;
     $this.css("width", dynamicWidth + "px");
     $arrow.css("left", dynamicWidth + dropdownArrowStaticArmLength + "px");
 });
 $(".selectClass").change();
});
```

There's some pitfalls with the length of the text vs the box width - this is no production code, just an example.

Better ways could be making "your own select box" with a combination of JS and CSS. Google `custom select` to get some ideas. Good luck!

Comment: this is the language select box and it's standalone one without border and transparent background like in my jsfiddle. I don't like this long gap between the arrow and the text. Like "Dutch" is short one but "Chinese Simplified" is long one. I've changed for the text move to arrow [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/46mvya90/2/) (point 2 - which I prefer better), but I can't make constant distance of the gap between text and the arrow and I notice another problem. The list of options (when you open) should show always from right to the left (from the arrow to the left).

Comment: Yes. It's a horrible solution. Aha. Standalone language select - sounds better :) I believe you're looking for something along the lines of [jQuery-nice-select](http://hernansartorio.com/jquery-nice-select/). (Never used it). Probably overkill, I'm sure you can put together what you need with less.

Comment: thx, I'll check your link. I've almost got it work [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/46mvya90/4/), works fine only on FF. Chrome or Opera - the options are with the padding as well, which is bad and I've read that this can't be fixed. So, it seems that I have to build my own select.